# Port 80 still blocked even after port forwarding and disabling firewall

Tags: apache, http, ip, port, portforwarding

I have been trying to open port 80 for my Apache server. However, the port is still closed, even after port forwarding it on my router and disabling every firewall. I have checked the port before and after starting Apache, and something does start listening, however the port is still closed. Could another app be closing it?
Does anybody have any insight to what might be causing this?

Comment: What OS?  You could have a firewall software blocking the port.  Impossible to know without much more details.  FYI this is off topic on SO, you will have more results with a well formulated question on OS administration forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody having the same problem, the issue was that my ISP was by default blocking Port 80, so I had to change the settings on my router and redo the port forwarding.

ISPs can block certain ports for various reasons such as security, so always check on their website beforehand.